# Toggle div using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use this jsfiddle but it's not working offline. Can you please point out the error: http://jsfiddle.net/2ofkr7ph/

This is my code but it's not working on local.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>BUILD</title>
<style>
.menu > li {
    display:inline-block;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:6px 10px;
    cursor:pointer;
    border:2px solid tomato;
    margin:5px;
}
.container {
    border:2px solid black;
    margin:5px;
}
.container > div {
    display:none;
}
.container > div:first-child {
    display:block;
}
</style>
<script>
var menu_elements = document.querySelectorAll('.menu>li'),
    menu_length = menu_elements.length;
for (var i = 0; i < menu_length; i++) {
    menu_elements[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        var target = document.querySelector('.container>.' + e.target.classList[0]); // clicked element
        Array.prototype.filter.call(target.parentNode.children, function (siblings) {
            siblings.style.display = 'none'; // hide sibling elements
        });
        target.style.display = 'block'; // show clicked element
    });
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="toggle1">One</li>
    <li class="toggle2">Two</li>
    <li class="toggle3">Three</li>
    <li class="toggle4">Four</li>
    <li class="toggle5">Five</li>
</ul>
<div class="container">
    <div class="toggle1">Here are the contents of 1.</div>
    <div class="toggle2">Here are the contents of 2..</div>
    <div class="toggle3">Here are the contents of 3...</div>
    <div class="toggle4">Here are the contents of 4....</div>
    <div class="toggle5">Here are the contents of 5.....</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It's working fine on JSFiddle website, but not working on local machine.

Comment: What's different on your local machine, any errors you're receiving?

Comment: did you include the jQuery on local machine

Comment: Please include jquery in on your localhost

Comment: I added <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script> but it won't work

Comment: Why would including jQuery help? There's no jQuery code there at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the script at the end of your , and then it'll work fine.

Comment: May I know the reason why it worked when I put it at the end ? @Alexandru

Comment: Because if you put it in the head, the script runs before other elements are initialized. It works on JSFiddle because the script is executed after the entire page is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

The script is loaded and executed BEFORE the HTML elements are encountered. You can move the script to below the BODY tag and it works offline.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

The contents inside the `script` tag need to be placed in some kind of function and the function needs to be called when the body loads, or else they won't run properly. Place all your Javascript code inside a `load` function like this:

```
<script>
    function load() {
        // rest of the code..
    }
</script>
```

and then set the function to be called when the document loads:

```
    <body onload="load()"> ...
```

Everything should then work properly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with your java script it is with the fact that you are writing your java script before your html.
This does not give JS enough time to load your html

An easy fix for this is to move your JS to the bottom or use something like `document.ready()`

Answer (score -2):

I've changed Your code part with jQuery and it's sugar. It's more cross-browser solution and saves You time.
Use this:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>BUILD</title>
<style>
.menu > li {
    display:inline-block;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:6px 10px;
    cursor:pointer;
    border:2px solid tomato;
    margin:5px;
}
.container {
    border:2px solid black;
    margin:5px;
}
.container > div {
    display:none;
}
.container > div:first-child {
    display:block;
}
</style>
  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
  <script>
    $(function(){
      $('.menu>li.toggle').click(function(){
        $('.togglable').hide();
        $('.togglable[data-id="'+$(this).data('id')+'"]').show();
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="toggle" data-id="1">One</li>
    <li class="toggle" data-id="2">Two</li>
    <li class="toggle" data-id="3">Three</li>
    <li class="toggle" data-id="4">Four</li>
    <li class="toggle" data-id="5">Five</li>
</ul>
<div class="container">
    <div class="togglable" data-id="1">Here are the contents of 1.</div>
    <div class="togglable" data-id="2">Here are the contents of 2..</div>
    <div class="togglable" data-id="3">Here are the contents of 3...</div>
    <div class="togglable" data-id="4">Here are the contents of 4....</div>
    <div class="togglable" data-id="5">Here are the contents of 5.....</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice! :) Somebody down-votes my answer without explaining why. Be a man!